# On convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

Let $X_a$ be a positive random variable indexed by parameter $a\in[0,+\infty)$. Suppose $X_a$ has all moments for any fixed $a$, but it explodes as $a\to+\infty$ meaning that $\mathbb{P}(X_a>x)\to1$ for any fixed $x\ge0$. Let $L(t,a)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-tX_a}]$, $t\ge0$. Let $c(a)>0$ be a monotonically decreasing function of $a\ge0$ such that $c(a)\to0+$ as $a\to+\infty$. It is known that the variable $c(a)X_a$ is approximately unit mean exponential for large $a$ in the sense that $L(c(a)t,a)\to1/(1+t)$ as $a\to+\infty$ for any fixed $t\ge0$. Since $L(c(a)t,a)\to1/(1+t)$ it follows that $\mathbb{P}(c(a)X_a>x)\to e^{-x}$ as $a\to+\infty$ for any fixed $x\ge0$. Can one infer that
$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathbb{P}(X_a>x)=O(c(a))
$$
as $a\to+\infty$?